# List elements order depending on complex condition

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Let's say, I have a list:

```
unordered_list = ['c-1','a-2','a-4','b-2','a-1','b-3','c-3','c-4']
```

And I've got some conditions:

1. first elements ending with 3 should be appended (but order from a to c should be kept)
2. then list should be ordered from a to c
3. but when ordering from a to c the endings must be ordered from 1 to 3

Result should look like:

```
ordered_list = ['b-3','c-3','a-1','a-2','a-4','b-2','c-1','c-4']
```

I've spent much time to find some **efficient way** to realize it in **Groovy**, but didn't succeed, since I'm beginner in it. 
Any tips will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the format of the strings? Are they always 3 chars long

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem , no, they actually look like "<gitreponame>-<gitbranchname>" , where gitreponame contains 2 or 3 words separated by .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for all the other lists, you can stream an array directly

```
    Stream.concat(Stream.of(unordered_list)
                    .filter(s -> s.endsWith("3"))
                    .sorted(),
            Stream.of(unordered_list))
            .filter(s -> !s.endsWith("3"))
            .sorted()
            .collect(toList());
```

Or for actual List:

```
    List<String> unorderedList = asList("c-1", "a-2", "a-4", "b-2", "a-1", "b-3", "c-3", "c-4");
    Stream.concat(unorderedList.stream()
                    .filter(s -> s.endsWith("3"))
                    .sorted(),
            unorderedList.stream()
                    .filter(s1 -> !s1.endsWith("3"))
                    .sorted())
            .collect(toList());
```

And finally, another way using a partition

```
    Map<Boolean, List<String>> endsWith3Partition = Stream.of(unordered_list)
            .sorted()
            .collect(partitioningBy(s -> s.endsWith("3")));
    List<String> sorted = new ArrayList<>(unordered.length);
    sorted.addAll(endsWith3Partition.get(true));
    sorted.addAll(endsWith3Partition.get(false));
```

Comment: I'd think he first two are more efficient since they don't create intermediate lists like the partition does.

Comment: @Olia I hightly recommend https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL to make streams much simpler

Comment: If anyone sees this and is confused, the original question was tagged Java, not Groovy, it's probably much simpler but similar in Groovy. @Olia for Groovy you could just use a single sort closure similar to the Comparator below

Answer (score 2):

You can write a **comparator**, like the one below:

```
Arrays.sort(unordered_list, new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
       String[] o1s = o1.split('-');
       String[] o2s = o2.split('-');
       boolean end1_3 = o1s[1].equals("3");
       boolean end2_3 = o2s[1].equals("3");
       if(end1_3 && end2_3) {
           return 0; //both end with 3
       } else if(end1_3) {
           return -1; //only the first ends with 3, so less than
       } else if(end2_3) {
           return 1; //only the second ends with 3, so greater than
       }
       if(!o1s[0].equals(o2s[0])) { // first group not same
           return o1s[0].compareTo(o2s[0]); // compare first groups
       }
       return o1s[1].compareTo(o2s[1]); // assume equal
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using Java 8's `stream`, e.g.:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"c-1","a-2","a-4","b-2","a-1","b-3","c-3","c-4"});

TreeMap<Boolean, List<String>> lists = list.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.toString().endsWith("3"), TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()));

final List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

lists.descendingMap().forEach((k, v) -> {
    Collections.sort(v);
    result.addAll(v);
});

System.out.println(result);
```